# PySpark: Exception in thread "dag-scheduler-event-loop" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: python, pyspark, k-means

I am trying to convert categorical to numerical values using `StringIndexer`, `OneHotEncoder` and `VectorAssembler` in order to apply K-means clustering in PySpark. Here's my code:

```
indexers = [
    StringIndexer(inputCol=c, outputCol="{0}_indexed".format(c))
    for c in columnList
]

encoders = [OneHotEncoder(dropLast=False, inputCol=indexer.getOutputCol(),
                          outputCol="{0}_encoded".format(indexer.getOutputCol()))
            for indexer in indexers
            ]

assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=[encoder.getOutputCol() for encoder in encoders], outputCol="features")


pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers + encoders + [assembler])
model = pipeline.fit(df)
transformed = model.transform(df)

kmeans = KMeans().setK(2).setFeaturesCol("features").setPredictionCol("prediction")
kMeansPredictionModel = kmeans.fit(transformed)

predictionResult = kMeansPredictionModel.transform(transformed)
predictionResult.show(5)
```

I am getting `Exception in thread "dag-scheduler-event-loop" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. How can I allocate more heap space in the code or better? Is it smart to allocate more space? Can I restrict my program to the available number of threads and heap space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run into the same problem. Increasing number of allowed processes for user helped. Run for example:

```
ulimit -u 4096
```